# How to clone a private git repository using Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Scenario:** I've created two repositories inside my GitLab account: '**work**' & '**project**'. There are multiple branches in each of the following repos. I'm currently in the ***project*** repo and have created the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

**Task:** I want to copy two files 'A' & 'B' from the feature branch of '**work**' repository to the current location (i.e., in the root of my ***project*** repository).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, just add it to your script section
`- git clone https://user:password@gitlab.com/group/project.git`

Or to download specific files
`- curl --header 'Private-Token: <your_access_token>' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/files/:filename\?ref\=:ref`

Also it will be a great practice to add Private-Token to project masked varible

You can get access token here
[image: access_token]

Comment: Can you please specify the parts which I need to change in the curl command with '<>'?

Comment: @MOHITBHATT update answer